# How to replace string in Golang?

Tags: string, go

I want to replace string except first and last alphabet.

For example:

```
handsome -> h******e

한국어    -> 한*어
```

This is my code:

```
var final = string([]rune(username)[:1]
for i :=0l i <len([]rune(username)); i++{
 if i >1 {
  final = final + "*"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you convert the string to `[]rune`, you can modify that slice and convert it back to `string` in the end:

```
func blur(s string) string {
    rs := []rune(s)
    for i := 1; i < len(rs)-1; i++ {
        rs[i] = '*'
    }
    return string(rs)
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(blur("handsome"))
fmt.Println(blur("한국어"))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/UIiUFHGiuEj)):

```
h******e
한*어
```

Note that this `blur()` function works with strings that have less than 3 characters too, in which case nothing will be blurred.